Numbering exercises by chapter and printing solutions by chapter in appendix
So, I have a basic tcolorbox that I want to write my exercises in. I want the exercises to be numbered by chapter, i.e. Exercise 1.1 is exercise 1 in chapter 1 (and still be able to print the answers in the appendix!). However, I was unable to do that. I currently have this MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtcolorbox{exercises}{%
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame empty,
    colback=yellow!20,
    breakable
}

\newtheorem{question}{Exercise}

\newcommand{\Exercise}[2]{
\begin{question}
    #1
\end{question}
\vspace{2mm}
\expandafter\gdef\csname answer:\thequestion\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand{\PrintExerciseSolutions}[2]{
\begin{exercises}
\newcount\i
\i = #1
\newcount\n
\n = \thequestion
\advance \n 1
\loop
\textbf{Solution~ \the\i.}
\csname answer:\the\i\endcsname\ \par\vspace{0.5cm}
\advance \i 1
\ifnum \i < \numexpr#2 +1\relax
\repeat
\end{exercises}
}%

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The start}

\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{Hello??}{Does this work?}
    \Exercise{This is the second one}{Does it still not work?}
\end{exercises}


\chapter{The second one}


\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{This is exercises in different chapters}{Does this work?}
    \Exercise{Another question}{This answer is unique.}
\end{exercises}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 1}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{1}{2}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{3}{4}

\end{document}

So, I use the \Exercise{<question>}{<solution>} to create numbered exercises, and then in the appendix I do \PrintExerciseSolutions{<start>}{<finish>} to get solutions for questions <start> to <finish>.
What I want is to be able to do \PrintExerciseSolutions{<chapter>} instead, and have the exercises numbered, in this MWE Exercise 2.1 instead of Exercise 3.


It is important that I am still able to print the solution in another chapter (appendix) than the exercise. So \newtheorem{question}{Exercise}[chapter] doesn't work, because it "breaks" the solutions in the appendix.

Update: Previously, I couldn't print the answers when I had the exercises inside a tcolorbox. However, I solved this issue. I used \gdef instead of \def inside \Exercise so that the answer command is defined globally and not locally. Thus, the answers is now printed. :)

Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

fixed it @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Your questions still asks about both numbering the exercises per chapter and printing them in the appendix. Why not solve one problem first?

You should take a look at the xsim package. I think it provides all the features you're looking on.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I solved the printing problem.

I sort of got a working solution. Here is a working example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xsim}

\newtcolorbox{exercises}{%
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame empty,
    colback=yellow!20,
    breakable
}

% \newtheorem{question}{Exercise}
\newcounter{questionDisplay}[chapter]
\setcounter{questionDisplay}{0}
\newcounter{Question}
\setcounter{Question}{0}
\newenvironment{question}{
    \stepcounter{questionDisplay}\stepcounter{Question}
    \textbf{Exercise \thechapter.\thequestionDisplay.}\itshape
}

\newcommand{\Exercise}[2]{
\begin{question}
    #1
\end{question}
\vspace{2mm}
\expandafter\gdef\csname answer:\theQuestion\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand{\PrintExerciseSolutions}[3]{
\begin{exercises}
\newcount\i
\i = #2
\newcount \j
\j = 1
\loop
\textbf{Solution~ #1.\the\j.}
\csname answer:\the\i\endcsname\ \par\vspace{0.5cm}
\advance \i 1
\advance \j 1
\ifnum \i < \numexpr#3 +1\relax
\repeat
\end{exercises}
}%

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The start}

\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{Hello??}{Does this work?}
    \Exercise{This is the second one}{Does it still not work?}
\end{exercises}


\chapter{The second one}


\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{This is exercises in different chapters}{Chap 2}
    \Exercise{Another question}{This answer is unique.}
\end{exercises}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 1}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{1}{1}{2}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{2}{3}{4}



\end{document}


The only thing I don't like with this solution is that you still have to specify the start and end. I.e. \PrintExerciseSolutions{<chapter>}{<start>}{<end>}, where the  and  are the "absolute" counter for the exercises. In this MWE, exercise 2.1 has the absolute count of 3.
Another drawback is that if I do \PrintExerciseSolutions{3}{4}{4}, this will produce the solution of Exercise 2.2, but will have the text Solution 3.1:

